# iOS and Swift: Async vs sync in new thread to fetch files from URL

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

This is a general "best practice" question.

I need to fetch a few images from a remote server, and save them in my app's file system. Now, I know there are a few ways to do that, but i'm trying to figure out what's the most common one nowadays.
Generally speaking, I can either use an asynchronous request, or open a different thread and run a synchronous request. On the surface, both would work. But under the hood, I want to make sure i'm utilising my hardware as much as possible. Specifically, would an async request automatically utilise a multi core hardware, or will it run on the main thread in a round-robin kind of way.

So what's considered to be the best practice here? Should I use a method that's known to be asynced (such as **NSURLSession**'s **dataTaskWithURL**), or use GCD and run the synced **NSData(contentsOfURL:)** on a different thread?

Comment: I would suggest that either way is probably fine. A task like that will be limited by the network anyway so it doesn't matter too much about multi core or whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually think this is an interesting question.

In my opinion both are really equivalent from a performance POV (although I'm obviously not privy to the NSURLSession implementation I would imagine it uses GCD under the hood (or maybe `NSOperationQueue`)).

`NSURLSession` provides an object orientated and controlled way to interact with web content.
GCD with NSData is a much simpler paradigm, but what you gain in simplicity you lose in **control**.

For example, take the points made [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/using-blocks-dispatchasync-vs-nsurlsession):

*`NSURLSession` a high level API to make it easy to perform HTTP requests. Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) is a concurrency API. You can use GCD to achieve asynchronous calls but then you have to do all the network management manually.*

Comment: NSURLSession indeed makes more sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DarkshoreGrouper, pleasure!